# How do I make an IconButton in android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-paper

I'm studying android after using react native for quite a while and I can't seem to find anything about IconButtons in android like the ones here:

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icon-button.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an `ImageButton` in Android.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favorite_imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border"
    android:tint="?attr/colorOnBackground"       
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/up_navigation_imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/game_link_imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/up_navigation_imageButton"
    tools:src="@drawable/ic_star_border" />
```